# Creating a column formula in excel, changing only one variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very basic excel file for looking at the cost of shares and calculating a profit/loss %.

I have the initial purchase price in cell E3 and I have the current share price in F3. I have calculated the percentage profit/loss in G3 by the following formula

=(F3/E3)*100 - 100

What I now want is to be able to apply this formula to the whole G column as I enter a new share price into the F column, it will use E3 as a constant in the formula to calculate daily profit/loss. So the new formula I want is effectively;

=(Fi/E3)*100 - 100
Where Fi = F3, F4, F5, F6 and so on...

I have tried dragging the cell down to extend the formula, which works to an extent but it does not keep E3 constant so I get a divide by zero error.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with `=(F3/E$3)*100 - 100`. The **$** is an absolute anchor that tells the formula not to change the **3** in **E$3** when filled down.

If there is no value in column F, you can have the result returned as a zero-length string (e.g. `""`) which will make the cell in column G that holds the formula look blank.

```
=IF(LEN(F3), (F3/E$3)*100 - 100, "")
```

Comment: Excellent. However this has raised a further question. Now in my G column, I just have a whole series of ' -100 ' in each cell. When I enter a value into my F column it calculates correctly, so there is nothing wrong with the functionality but it there a way to have the columns blank?

I have tried an extra bracket around the formula but no luck.

Comment: See my addendum above.

Answer (score 4):

Use an absolute reference for E3 in the formula:

$e$3

This will lock the reference if you drag the cell down.

Answer (score 0):

The other way around, if you want to lock the character:

```
=(F3/$E3)*100 - 100
```